# automated check if two SQL queries are semantically equal

Tags: sql

I got two queries:

```
'UPDATE foo SET bar = baz WHERE a = b AND c = d'
```

and

```
'UPDATE foo SET bar = baz WHERE c = d AND a = b'
```

both are semantically equal (they do the same), but a simple compare would state that they are different as the first has `a = b AND c = d` whereas the second uses `c = d AND a = b`.

**How can I check whether both queries are semantically equal?**

This is an obviously easy example that can be solved by simple alphabetic sorting of the syntax tree at the `WHERE` node. I am interested in a generic approach that can also solve more complex queries - even with subqueries.

***A further restriction is that I do not have access to the database and can only use the strings of the queries. Thus RUNNING the queries is out of question as it would NOT reflect on the equality of the queries.***

An example for the bold text above:

FooTable:

```
A |  B |  C
1 | xx | xx
2 | yy | zz
```

FooTable': (FooTable' is FooTable on a different database)

```
A |  B |  C
1 | xx | xx
2 | ee | zz
3 | ss | xx
```

Example why running the queries will NOT yield valid results:

**1) Queries on the same database:**

```
UPDATE FooTable SET B = 'rr' WHERE C = 'xx'
```

AND

```
UPDATE FooTable SET B = 'rr' WHERE C = 'xx' OR B = 'ss'
```

Both queries will RESULT in exactly the same but are trivially not equal.

**2) Queries when including different databases (same schema but different data):**

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM FooTable where C = 'xx'
```

AND

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM FooTable' where C = 'xx'
```

Those two queries are trivially semantically equal but will NOT yield the same results.

Comment: Run them, and compare the result set?

Comment: Run explain plan on both of them, and then run them both and compare the results?

Comment: @Stewart I do not have access to the database the queries are run on. Even if, the overhead of running/comparing and resetting the database after seems like an approach with a lot of overhead. This would thus not work with massive amounts of queries. (Same @sagi)

Comment: @sagi: I don't think the execution plan is sufficient. Different queries might have the same plan or semantically identical queries might have different plans.

Comment: @sagi how would you compare the results of an `UPDATE` query? The only idea I'd have is to export the database and hash it - but this does not seem efficient. Furthermore the result would certainly be database dependent and thus not necessarily reflect on the equality of the queries.

Comment: Run queries as SELECT like this: SELECT bar, baz FROM foo WHERE your condition (the same thing for the second UPDATE) and check the result set if the same.

Comment: You cannot. The DMBS can rewrite a subquery with a join or viceversa, use information in the constraints, and do weird stuff.

Comment: When you say "check", do you mean an automatic check, or a manual verification?

Comment: @Tobb check means algorithm/tool/magic unicorn that does the deal. It needs to be automated.

Comment: So this query using `IN`: `select * from core.[Group] where Id IN(select groupId from core.GroupPermission)` should be equal to this one using `EXISTS`: `select * from core.[Group] where exists (select null from core.GroupPermission where core.GroupPermission.GroupId = core.[Group].Id)`?

Comment: @Magnus If I am not misunderstanding the intention of the query, those should be considered equal as they should yield equal results on equal databases regardless of changes of the content of the database in between tests. (see FooTable and FooTable' examples)

Comment: @Sim Then I think it would be impossible to solve by just analyzing the query.

Comment: @Magnus why? I admit that the problem is not trivial and in such extreme cases your assumption might hold but can reducing the allowed complexity of queries push the problem into solvable space? I am currently looking through scientific literature but cannot find either a solution or a proof that the problem is not solvable, which would be considered an proper answer.

Comment: I don't know of any existing tool myself, if Google cannot provide one - then you'll most likely have to build a query parser yourself if you want to check the two expression trees against each other and using own functionality. And with SQL it can become quite a daunting task given how much functionality can be combined to give the same results. Easy way is however as others have said - just check the results versus each other.

Comment: Consider a table, `t`. Consider a synonym, `s`, that is applied to `t` (or, if your database system doesn't support synonyms, a view `v` which selects all columns from `t` and applies no filters). There is *no* way to determine just by inspecting two queries, where one references `t` and the other references `s` (or `v`) that they are identical.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, execution plans would be the same, wouldn't they? Let existing optimizer do the heavy work and compare only the execution plans.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - with a lot of provisos, usually. You'd need to ensure that you're the only user accessing that DB, that your queries don't modify the data, that you're not facing off against a malicious sys-admin, etc. Otherwise, there are plenty of ways for two identical queries to be optimized differently.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is completely correct and I did not previously consider views. But for the sake of the question and for the context I want to use the answers in it can be assumed that everything equal is named the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is indeed not trivial.

In essence, you'll have to build your own query parser and optimizer. This is the task of optimizer - to transform the query operators in an execution plan in such a way that the final result of the query remains the same for any possible data in the underlying tables (taking all constraints into account). Smart optimizers are able to generate identical plans for queries that look very different (such as `IN` vs `EXISTS`), they simplify and unify logic conditions in `WHERE` clause, can push predicates along the execution tree and do many other things.

Writing such optimizer from scratch would be hard, but you can have a look at existing open source databases (Postgres?) and see if you can borrow something from there.

Another, more practical approach could be utilizing one of the existing databases and instead of running the query, ask the optimizer to return you the generated execution plan. Then, instead of comparing original SQL text you can compare execution plans. If plans are the same, then the original queries are 100% equivalent. If plans are different, it is still possible that optimizer was not smart enough to deduce that the queries are equivalent, but you'll have to accept the possibility of false negatives.

I'd have a look at several different databases and see what kind of information you can get from their optimizers using built-in capabilities. In any case, the generated execution plan should be much more structured that original SQL text and it should be easier to compare them automatically.

Comment: this sounds like a sound option. I'll look into this and if it proofs viable I'll accept this as an answer. The current problem is that it is more an abstract idea than a (yet) practical solution, thus accepting it without verification might be premature.

Comment: I opted for a simpler but not 'perfect' method. I now remove all values in comparisons or assignments, remove all whitespaces and then order the syntax tree alphabetically to finally compare the strings. This is by far not what I initially wanted but simpler and currently sufficient for my problem. But as this is the only answer so far and sounds sound I accept this as the answer to the question.